# How to use an ODBC file source (.DSN) to export to excel with defined location but no defined filename, bringing up "select workbook"

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, export, odbc, dsn

How can I set up a DSN to direct to a specific location, but then allow me to select the file rather than writing to a specific file.

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)
UID=admin
UserCommitSync=Yes
Threads=3
SafeTransactions=0
ReadOnly=0
PageTimeout=5
MaxScanRows=8
MaxBufferSize=2048
FIL=excel 12.0
DriverId=1046
DefaultDir=Drive:\exportdirectory
DBQ=Drive:\exportdirectory\file.xlsx
```

The below will write to \exportdirectory\file.xlsx

If I use any of the following

```
DefaultDir=Drive:\exportdirectory\*xls*
(no DBQ)


DefaultDir=Drive:\exportdirectory\*
(no DBQ)

DefaultDir=Drive:\exportdirectory
DBQ=Drive:\exportdirectory\*xls*

DefaultDir=Drive:\exportdirectory
DBQ=Drive:\exportdirectory\*

DefaultDir=Drive:\exportdirectory
DBQ=*.xls*
```

I get the desired behaviour, but it's a bit of a hack: after an error message (trying to write to the file "*.xls* and failing) it brings up "select workbook" in the defaultdir.

Omitting DBQ just writes to the file ".xls" in the default directory, as does DBQ=*